# Function call on client connection to server

Tags: java, sockets

In socket programming using Java.I want a function call to happen whenever a client connects to the server. I'm stuck up here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there anything (a code) that you have tried already? As you are new, please read our [Tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class NewConnectionListener implements Runnable{

public static ServerSocket serverSocket;


public NewConnectionListener(){
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(500);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {

    while(true){
        try {
            Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
            callMethodWithNewSocket(s);
            System.out.println("new Client");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error getting Client");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

}
```

}

With this code everytime there is a new connection to port 500 on the server the method `callMethodWithNewSocket(Socket s)` will be called with the socket as a parameter.